# Cross-domain hubConnection with signalR

Tags: cross-domain, signalr

Persistent connections across different domains seem to work fine, judging by this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/GSEJp

But when I try to use a "hubConnection" instead, because my application uses hubs instead of raw connections, the browser complains about CORS. Open the Javascript Console in your browser and run this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/GSEJp/4/

Even though my Global.asax includes this code:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        if (this.Context.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            this.Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
            this.Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, Accept");
            this.Context.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

So what could be wrong? Is it simply that hubConnections don't work well across different domains, or could it be something on my side? I should mention that I can run normal XHR requests to that same MVC application from a local REST client (Postman), so it shouldn't be anything wrong on my side.

Thanks!

EDIT:

After some more digging I found that the signalr js file that is used in the first jsfiddle has a definition of this "xdomain" property. But it has no definition of "hubConnection", so that's why I switched to query.signalR-0.5.3.js. But that one has no definition of "xdomain". And that's probably why i get the CORS error.

Is there a version of the signalr js client that supports both xdomain and hubConnection?

Thanks again.

Comment: You're using the wrong version of SignalR. Use the latest (1.0 rc1). CORS headers are added automatically.

Comment: Ah, I didn't even know there was an 1.0. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As dfowler wrote in his comment, the problem was that I was using an old version of SignalR.

Note for others who read this: you need to set jsonp: true in the connection options for it to work.